# How can I convert a gpa calculator to use upper and lower case grade arguments?

Tags: python

I am creating a GPA calculator which takes in 4 grades and gives the GPA. I want it to be able to use upper case letters 'A' and lower case letters 'a' and so on through 'F' 'f'. Right now it will only use upper case letters. How can I convert it to use both without changing the dictionary?

```
import sys
def gpa_calculator(grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4):
    points = 0
    i = 0
    grade_c ={'A':4.0, 'A-':3.66, 'B+':3.33, 'B':3.0,
      'B-':2.66,'C+':2.33,'C':2.0,'C-':1.66,'D+':1.33,'D':1.00,'D-':.66,'F':0.00}

    if grades != []:
        for grade in grades:
            points += grade_c[grade]
        gpa = points / len(grades)
        return gpa
    else:
        return None

    grade1 = sys.argv[1]
    grade2 = sys.argv[2]
    grade3 = sys.argv[3]
    grade4 = sys.argv[4]

    grades = grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4
    grades = gpa_calculator(grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4)
    print('My GPA is',(grades))
```

Comment: You could do [.upper()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_upper.htm#:~:text=Python%20String%20upper%20%28%29%20Method%201%20Description.%20Python,example%20shows%20the%20usage%20of%20upper%20%28%29%20method.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least two options

1  Add the "lower case" version of the keys to the dictionary as the dictionary key is case-sensitive. Thereby creating a larger dictionary and somewhat unnecessary repeated code.

```
grade_c = {'A':4.0, 'A-':3.66, 'B+':3.33, 'B':3.0, 'B-':2.66,'C+':2.33,'C':2.0,'C-':1.66,'D+':1.33,'D':1.00,'D-':.66,'F':0.00, 'a':4.0, 'a-':3.66, 'b+':3.33, 'b':3.0, 'b-':2.66,'c+':2.33,'c':2.0,'c-':1.66,'d+':1.33,'d':1.00,'d-':.66,'f':0.00 }
```

2. Keep your dictionary as is and take the passed in command line arguments and use the `str.upper()` method to convert and store them as uppercase. The user can pass in either any case and it will be converted to uppercase for handling by your current dictionary and code.

```py
    grade1 = sys.argv[1].upper()
    grade2 = sys.argv[2].upper()
    grade3 = sys.argv[3].upper()
    grade4 = sys.argv[4].upper()
```